# Passing a pointer to a multidimensional enum array

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, enums

I am still trying to get my head around using pointers to arrays and while making a simple game I have encountered the following issue:

in a header file, I have an enum defined as:
`typedef enum {UNDEF, YELLOW, RED} State;`

then, in my main function, I have two multidimensional arrays as:

```
State particle_exists[WIDTH][LENGTH]; 
State temp_particle_exists[WIDTH][LENGTH];
```

I am trying to pass a pointer to these arrays, like so:

```
clear_grid(&particle_exists[WIDTH][LENGTH]);
```

with `clear_grid()` defined as:

```
void clear_grid(State *particle_exists[WIDTH][LENGTH])
{
 // code that clears this array (sets it all to UNDEF basically )
{
```

this however, gives me the error:

```
main.c:57:16: warning: passing argument 1 of 'clear_grid' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     clear_grid(&particle_exists[WIDTH][LENGTH]);
                ^
In file included from main.c:18:0:
printer.h:24:6: note: expected 'State * (*)[6] {aka enum <anonymous> * (*)[6]}' but argument is of type 'State * {aka enum <anonymous> *}'
 void clear_grid(State *particle_exists[WIDTH][LENGTH]);
      ^~~~~~~~~~
```

I have tried looking for answers but none that I could find worked in my case. So is what I'm doing logical, and if yes, how can I fix this issue?

Comment: `clear_grid(&particle_exists[WIDTH][LENGTH]);`  -> `clear_grid(&particle_exists);`. But I imagine that you don't really want to pass a pointer

Comment: @EugeneSh. I tried that as well, that gave me the following error: `main.c:57:16: warning: passing argument 1 of 'clear_grid' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     clear_grid(&particle_exists);
                ^
In file included from main.c:18:0:
printer.h:24:6: note: expected 'State * (*)[6] {aka enum <anonymous> * (*)[6]}' but argument is of type 'State (*)[7][6] {aka enum <anonymous> (*)[7][6]}'
 void clear_grid(State *particle_exists[WIDTH][LENGTH]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the array is `particle_exists`. It is not `particle_exists[WIDTH][LENGTH]`.

So when you want to refer to the array in an expression, you use its name, `particle_exists`, not `particle_exists[WIDTH][LENGTH]`.

The declaration `State particle_exists[WIDTH][LENGTH];` declares an object named `particle_exists` and says it has `WIDTH` rows, each of which has `LENGTH` elements, each of which has type `State`. The declaration describes the array named `particle_exists`.

In an expression, `particle_exists` refers to the array, and `particle_exists[i][j]` refers to element `j` of row `i`. So `particle_exists[WIDTH][LENGTH]` attempts to refer to element `LENGTH` of row `WIDTH`. However, there is no such element, because the elements are indexed from 0 to `LENGTH`−1, inclusive, and the rows are indexed from 0 to `WIDTH`−1 inclusive. `WIDTH` and `LENGTH` are outside those bounds.

The code `clear_grid(&particle_exists[WIDTH][LENGTH])` attempts to pass the address of an element that does not exist. If it did exist, the element would have type `State`, so its address would have type `State *`.

The code `clear_grid(&particle_exists)` would pass the address of the array, and there is a way to make that work. However, it is more common in C to use ``clear_grid(particle_exists)`. When an array is used in this way, it will be automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. Its first element is a row of` LENGTH`elements. So the type of a pointer to the first row will be`State (*)[LENGTH]`.

`void clear_grid(State *particle_exists[WIDTH][LENGTH])` declares `clear_grid` to have a parameter that is an array of `WIDTH` rows of `LENGTH` elements in which each element is a pointer to `State`. That is not what you want with anything discussed above. `[WIDTH]` and `[LENGTH]` grammatically bind to `particle_exists` before `*`, so you would be declaring the parameter to be a (two-dimensional) array whose elements are pointers. To declare a pointer to a two-dimensional array, you would use `void clear_grid(State (*particle_exists)[WIDTH][LENGTH])`. That would work if you passed `&particle_exists`.

However, as mentioned above, it is more common to pass a pointer to the first row. With this, use `void clear_grid(State particle_exists[WIDTH][LENGTH])`. This nominally declares the parameter to be a two-dimensional array. However, parameters declared as arrays are automatically adjusted to be pointers, so this declaration is the same as `void clear_grid(State (*particle_exists)[LENGTH])`. You can also use that.

Then `clear_grid(particle_exists)` will pass a pointer to the first row, which is an array of `LENGTH` elements of type `State`, and `clear_grid` will accept a parameter that is a pointer to an array of `LENGTH` elements of type `State`.

Inside `clear_grid`, you can use the parameter with subscripts in the same way you would use a two-dimensional array. `particle_exists[i][j]` will refer to element `j` of row `i`.

Comment: thank you, I was stuck on this all evening. `void clear_grid(State (*particle_exists)[WIDTH][LENGTH])` did solve my issue. And I guess I'm using an older book or something because it keeps hammering on that passing a pointer to an array is faster than passing the array itself, I did not know about the automatic pointer conversion you describe.